# Invalid User resolver, callable or UserResolver FQCN expected error [Laravel Auditing 4.1]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-auditing

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Laravel Auditing 4.1. I want to record the price changes on Variant model, I installed the Auditing 4.1 package. See my code,

**config/audit.php**

```
'implementation' => OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::class,

'user' => [
    'primary_key' => 'id',
    'foreign_key' => 'variant_id',
    'model'       => App\Variant::class,
    'resolver'    => App\Variant::class,
],
```

**app/Models/Variant.php**

```
use OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable as AuditableContract;

class Variant extends BaseModel implements AuditableContract{

   use Auditable;
 --------Code here----------------
}
```

Using this code when I try to insert data to database, This error will come,

```
 UnexpectedValueException
 Invalid User resolver, callable or UserResolver FQCN expected
```

How can I fix this error and record my changes on `audits` table?

Comment: does your `App\User` model implements `OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\UserResolver` interface?

Comment: @Chay22 When I implements this an error "Interface 'App\Models\OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\UserResolver' not found" will get. I need to record the changes on variants table only. How can I do this?

Comment: @VinodVT because PHP namespacing

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the class (`App\Variant::class`) you configured in your `config/audit.php` to handle **User** resolution, does not implement the `OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\UserResolver` contract.

So, if you really want to use `App\Variant::class` as your **User** resolver class, this is how it should look like:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable as AuditableContract;

class Variant extends BaseModel implements AuditableContract, UserResolver
{
    use Auditable;

    public static function resolveId()
    {
        return Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier() : null;
    }

    // More code here
}
```

When in doubt, have a look at the [General Configuration](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/4.1/general-configuration) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a solution:

To solve the problem, I created a resolver and implemented the following logic:

```
<?php

namespace App\AuditResolvers;

class UserResolver  implements \OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\UserResolver
{
    public static function resolve()
    {
        return auth()->check() ? auth()->user() : null;
    }
}
```

then I configured my audit.php:

```
 'user' => [
       'morph_prefix' => 'user',
        'guards'       => [
            'web',
            'api'
        ],
       'resolver' => App\AuditResolvers\UserResolver::class,
    ],
```

Finally, in my Model User I implemented the method:

```
public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return auth()->user()->id;
    }
```

Seguir as instruções da documentação:
https://laravel-auditing.com/guide/audit-resolvers.html#user-resolver

Comment: please write completely in english